# GCC obtrusively optimizes one fragment of my code that I don't want to be optimized and I made everything volatile

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

I have function inportb. Code is as follows:

```
static inline volatile uint8_t inportb(volatile uint16_t port)
{
        uint8_t retval;

        asm volatile("inb %%dx,%%al" : "=a"(retval) : "dN"(port));
        return retval;
}
```

(outportb works similarly)

And here's my code which is incorrectly optimized by GCC:

```
    // write EOI
    outportb(0x20, 0x20);

    // Lowest bit of status will be set if buffer is not empty
    if (inportb(KEYBOARD_STATUS_PORT) & 0x01) {
        keycode = inportb(KEYBOARD_DATA_PORT);
        ...
```

Here you have objdump:

```
0000000000100660 <kbd_irq>:
  100660:   b8 20 00 00 00          mov    $0x20,%eax
  100665:   ba 20 00 00 00          mov    $0x20,%edx
  10066a:   ee                      out    %al,(%dx)
  10066b:   ec                      in     (%dx),%al    <-- Hey! I want it to read from 0x64!
  10066c:   a8 01                   test   $0x1,%al
  10066e:   0f 84 9d 00 00 00       je     100711 <kbd_irq+0xb1>
  100674:   ec                      in     (%dx),%al    <-- It should read from 0x60 here.
```

Comment: Maybe `#pragma GCC optimize 0` can help? see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes

Comment: Where are the magic numbers 0x64 and 0x60 coming from?

Comment: are you sure you didn't set KEYBOARD_STATUS_PORT and KEYBOARD_DATA_PORT as 0x20 by mistake?

Comment: And are you sure dN is correct? d means it should be in the dx register, but N means it should be an immediate value. Maybe the combination confuses the compiler.

Comment: @user253751 You were right. I am not experienced with assembler inlines. "dN" should be in normal function, but then I made it into inline and now it should be just "d".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assembly statement says the input value `port` can be either `dx` or an immediate value. But instead of using the actual value, you just wrote `%%dx`! If the compiler decides it can be an immediate value, well, your assembly code *totally ignores that* and uses dx anyway.

Instead of `%%dx` try using `%1`, which means the second input/output value (as they start from 0). In this case it means the `port` input.

Or, change `dN` to `d` so the value is always in dx.